# Is it possible for protocols to have a default implementation of static factory methods?

Tags: swift, protocols

Consider a protocol that have a factory method:

```
public protocol Frobnicator {

  func frobnicate()

  static func makeRightFrobnicator() -> Frobnicator
}

private class SomeFrobnicatorImplementation: Frobnicator { ... }
private class AnotherFrobnicatorImplementation: Frobnicator { ... }

public extension Frobnicator {

  static func makeRightFrobnicator() -> Frobnicator {
    if something {
      return SomeFrobnicatorImplementation()
    } else {
      return AnotherFrobnicatorImplementation()
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to construct different implementors at different times. The implementors themselves are private to the module, whereas the protocol is public to use in the client code.

When I try the code similar to that above, I get “Static member `makeRightFrobnicator` cannot be used on protocol metatype `Frobnicator.Protocol`.”

Is there any way around it, or should I just use a free function?

Comment: This is what the Factory Pattern is for.

Comment: @Dai, yes, although the question is about whether or not I can use default implementation of protocol static methods.

Comment: "the question is about whether or not I can use default implementation of protocol static methods" Then why don't you say that in the question? This isn't about protocols having static methods at all. It's about protocol _extensions_ providing an _implementation_ of a static method.

Comment: @matt, indeed; sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static function implementation is legal:

```
protocol P {
    static func f() -> P
    init()
}

extension P {
    static func f() -> P {return self.init()}
}
```

But you'll notice that in order to get it to compile, I had to guarantee to the compiler that I have in hand a legal way to make a P so as to able to return one.

The issue in *your* code is the attempt to return a specific adopter of your protocol, like a SomeFrobnicatorImplementation. A protocol is agnostic as to who adopts it. To put it another way, you cannot guarantee within the protocol definition that SomeFrobnicatorImplementation will in fact be an adopter of this protocol. Thus, that part of your code is illegal.

Comment: I did not downvote you. I appreciate the effort, just wanted to add that `return self.init()` does compile, whereas `return X()` oddly does not.
https://repl.it/Ecm0/1
https://repl.it/Ecm0/0

Comment: `return X.init()`. But only if the compiler knows that that is legal. It cannot be a specific P adopter, for how can a protocol know who it's adopters are?

Comment: The above compiles, but when trying to use it with `P.f()` I get the error message "error: static member 'f' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'P.Protocol'". Even after I change the code to this:

    protocol P {
        static func f() -> P
        init()
    }
    
    extension P {
        static func f() -> P {return S.init()}
    }
    
    struct S: P {
    }
    
    P.f()

Comment: For some reason indenting the code with four spaces did not work.

Comment: @kareman "but when trying to use it with `P.f()`" Sure, you can't send a message to a protocol! You would have to send a message to an _adopter_ of a protocol. The adopter is an object; a protocol is just a protocol (literally, a set of rules).